# WPF, загрузка и отображение страницы отображения картинок скаченных из Интернета

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте! У меня такой вопрос: я хочу скачать, находясь на стартовой странице своей программы, картинки из интернета и через определённую функцию присвоить их коллекции.

После этого  я перехожу со стартовой страницы программы на страницу с картинками, но происходит некоторое зависание интерфейса программы, как видно из кода Dispatcher-а у меня нет. и я не знаю что делать.

Кусок WPF, это "Плитка" соотношением 5 х 6 изображений:

```html
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentMedias}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="5" Rows="6" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Border Width="176" Height="247"  
              Margin="20,20,0,0">
              <Grid>
                  <Image Source="{Binding    Path=Images, IsAsync=True}"/>
              </Grid>
           </Border>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Кусок C#:

```css
for (int i = 0; i < RecentMedias.Count(); i++)
{
   int temp = i;
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
      DownloadInst(RecentMedias[temp]);
   });
}

public void DownloadInst(SelectedMedia m)
{
   while (m.DownloadError)
   {
      try
      {
         System.Net.WebRequest request =
                               System.Net.WebRequest.Create(m._Media.Images.LowResolution.Url);
         System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

         var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
         using (System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
         {
                          responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
         }

         BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
         image.BeginInit();
         image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;
         image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
         image.StreamSource = memoryStream;
         image.EndInit();
         image.Freeze();

         m.Images = image;
         m.DownloadError = false;
     }
     catch
     {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        App.Log.Write("Не удалось скачать инстаграмм");
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите возможно у вас, где-то null. Посмотрите на число элементов в коллекции. 
Для загрузки картинок я использую код:

```
public void AddImages(string[] images)
        {
            if (_images == null)
                ImagesScroll._images = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

            foreach (var link in images)
            {
                try
                {
                    var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
                    imageSource.BeginInit();
                    imageSource.UriSource = new Uri(link);
                    imageSource.EndInit();

                    ImagesScroll._images.Add(imageSource);
                }
                catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Но у меня идёт загрузка картинок отдельными потоками и подгружаются в интерфейс загруженной страницы не сразу.

Comment: Но вы проверяли под дебагом коллекция картинок не равна null и в ней есть картинки. BitmapImage самостоятельно в отдельном потоке скачивает картинку и нет необходимости получать картинку средствами WebRequest.